# How can I sync a SQL Server view to a Postgres table?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, synchronization, etl, database-migration

I need to sync data from several tables in a legacy SQL Server db (source) to a single table in a Postgres db (target). The schema of the source db is absurd, so the query to select the data takes a very long time to run. I'm planning to create an indexed view in the source db, and then somehow sync that indexed view to the Postgres table.

Right now, I simply have a scheduled task that drops the Postgres table (target) and then recreates it from scratch by running the complex query in the source db. This was quick to set up, and it ensures that changes in the source db always eventually make it to the target db, but recreating the table every few hours is (understandably) very slow and expensive. I need a way to replicate ongoing changes (only the new/updated data) from the source view to the target table. Is there a (relatively) simple way to do this?

I'm somewhat familiar with CDC, but I understand that CDC cannot be used on a view, so I don't believe that's an option. Adding "updated at" timestamps to the source tables is not an option, so I can't use that approach. I could add a hash column to the source tables, or maybe add a hash column to the view, so that's an option if that would work. Is there an existing tool/service that does what I need?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to view SQL Server DB data in PostgreSQL, then you can also tds_fdw.
https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw

Also, there are some third-party tools which could help you to achieve your goal, for example, SymmetricDS
http://www.symmetricds.org/about/overview